# 'cURLcurl error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate' usando Windows Server, IIS y laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, iis

estoy haciendo un sistema usando el framework de laravel 10, Windows Server con IIS para alojarlo en un servidor, y que realiza consultas a una API empresarial.

Cuando estoy haciendo pruebas de manera local en mi computadora todo funciona correctamente, sin embargo, en el servidor al intentar hacer una peticion a la API, me aparece ese error, he estado buscando alguna solucion aunque todo lo que encuentro es una solucion para cuando se usa un servidor con Linux, mientras que yo estoy usando uno con Windows